# Changing the text color of specific word when I type in the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change the color of the specific word that I typed in edittext. but this code only change the word once. When I type another function it doesn't change the color.

```
tt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            final String FUNCTION = "function";
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int index = s.toString().indexOf(FUNCTION);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    s.setSpan(
                            new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN),
                            index,
                            index + FUNCTION.length(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) will always give the index of first found value so you need to loop through your string and find all the `function` string and apply span on it and to search from specific index use [`indexOf (String str, int fromIndex)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
// a single object to apply on all strings 
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan( Color.GREEN);    
String s1 = s.toString();
int in=0; // start searching from 0 index

// keeps on searching unless there is no more function string found 
while ((in = s1.indexOf(FUNCTION,in)) >= 0) {
    s.setSpan(
        fcs,
        in,
        in + FUNCTION.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    // update the index for next search with length
    in += FUNCTION.length();
}
```

---

To avoid matching `div` from `divide` you need to use `regex` `\\b` where `\\b` mean word boundary to avoid matching `div` with `divide`

```
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan( Color.GREEN);    
String s1 = s.toString();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b"+FUNCTION+"\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);

// keeps on searching unless there is no more function string found 
while (matcher.find()) {
    s.setSpan(
            fcs,
            matcher.start(),
            matcher.end(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Comment: I am making a code editor on android. Can I use this for Syntax highlighter? or Is there any tool that I can use regarding text highlighting?

Comment: yes you can or the other way is using `Html.fromHtml` function which required to manipulate the sting with `html` code

Comment: Last question sir. I declared a string that carries "div" word. but when I type a "divide" word, the div, in the word divide also change the color.

Comment: now you we need a `regex` solution , wait let me update the answe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138047/discussion-between-dianne-cole-and-pavneet-singh).